# How to hide a link in a cell of a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which displays a data from the database. In one of the tables in this database have a column to **store details about attanchment file**. If the **attachment is available** that column value will set as "YES". **Otherwise** it will set as "NO". What I want to do is, show a link to view the attachment. But if cell value of the column is "NO" (when there is no attachment) the link must be hidden.

> Note : I know how to view a file. Here what Im expecting is to hide the link in the cell which doesn't have an attachment.

This is what I have done upto now.

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
     grdSo.DataSource = ds;
     grdSo.DataBind();
     for(int i=0; i <ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
     {
          if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].Equals("NO"))
          {
               grdSo.Rows[i].Cells[6].Visible = false;
          }
         else
         {
               grdSo.Rows[i].Cells[6].Visible = true;
         }
     }
}
```

I could hide the cell using this code. But unfortunately this hides the lines of the cell too. How can I avoid it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ASPX Code :**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField Visible="false" DataField="id" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Has Attachment">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAtt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("HasAtt") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Attachment">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAtt" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnAtt_Click" Visible="false">View</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**CS Code :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        //Here you write databind logic
        // Datasource table of GridView1 should contain 'HasAtt' and 'id' as its binded to label.
    }

    private void ViewAttachment(int id)
    {
        //Here you write your logic to view attachment.
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) // checking if row is datarow or not
        {
            Label lblHasAtt = e.Row.FindControl("lblAtt") as Label;
            LinkButton lbtnViewAtt = e.Row.FindControl("lbtnAtt") as LinkButton;
            lbtnViewAtt.Visible = (lblHasAtt.Text.ToLower() == "yes");
        }
    }

    protected void lbtnAtt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lbtnViewAtt = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow grw = lbtnViewAtt.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(this.GridView1.Rows[grw.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text); // retriving value of first column on 'lbtnAtt' click row.
        this.ViewAttachment(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to do this is to use server side control like `LinkButton` to view the link that you want to show and set the visibility of the control as per your requirement in the `OnRowDataBound` event of the gridview.

Below is the code to show/hide LinkButton on `OnRowDataBound` event.

```
protected void gridId_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          DataSourceClass varData = (DataSourceClass)e.Row.DataItem;
          // check if your data have flag to show the link
          if(varData.show)
            ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("linkbuttonId")).Visible = true;
          else
            ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("linkbuttonId")).Visible = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: As per the question you updated, you can find the label and as we did for linkbutton in RowDataBound and check for related text of that label to set visibility of linkbutton.

Answer (score 1):

I recall being able to parse through the grid view by using a for each for the rows and using a for statement for columns.
If I recall correctly, you can grab an item ie
row.Item[i]

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in  GridView1.Rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        // here you can do the logic to decide whether to show or hide the text for this cell
    }
}
```

Sorry for formatting responding on my phone.

Comment: @ Brett, I have added the code to my question. It hides the cell value. I've explained it more in the question please take a look at it.

Comment: You could also dynamically add a control to display a link in the given cell and transfer the text of the cell to the item. The said item could then have its visible property set to false @user6592730